# Extjs4 Grid listeners for arrow key

Tags: javascript, extjs4, listener

I have a grid in Extjs4 and I'm using itemclick in listeneres to start an action when I select a row in a grid.
this is my code:

```
MyGrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel',{
    // code
    ,listeners : {
        itemclick: function(dv, record, item, index, e) {
            // doing something
        }
    }
});
```

But I want to start the event by selecting rows with arrow keys and not only with the mouse.
 hope my question is clear and thank you for helping.

Comment: Listen to the `selectionchange` event on the `SelectionModel`.